# library gcc dll could not be found error when I share my executable

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, exe

I have written some code for calculating DC voltage with iterative method for one of my electronics lessons at college. And I wanted to share it with one of my friends at college. It works on my computer but when I build it and shared it with my friend as an .exe file he said he gets this error:

*library gcc dll could not be found*

I used libraries which I am ashamed of using, but I had to use them because of Windows' UTF-8. I also know they have portability issues which I guess is the problem.

I build it with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -g iterativeFormulaCalculatorForDirectVoltage.cpp -o iterativeFormulaCalculatorForDirectVoltage.exe
```

Both I and my friend use Windows 10. Does he need to install minGW on his computer? It does not make sense that if someone wants to open the executable file thay should downloaded the compiler?

my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h> //for getch(). Sorry about that..

int main(){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); // Make console output utf-8

    std::string sup5 =   u8"\u2075";   //superscript 5 symbol
    std::string sup1 =   u8"\u00B9";   //superscript 1 symbol
    std::string supNeg = u8"\u207B";   //superscript negative sign symbol
    std::string multi =  u8"\u00D7";   //multiplication symbol
    std::string ohm =    u8"\u2126";   //greek letter ohm symbol

    double new_V_D, V_PP, R, I_S = 0;  //Diode Voltage, Source Voltage, Resistance and Saturation Current
    double V_T = 0.026;         //Thermal Voltage

    double old_V_D = 0.6;       //Initial Voltage guess (Volt)
    V_PP = 5;                   //(Volt)
    R = 1;                      //(kOhm)
    I_S = 0.000000000000002;    // 2 * 10^-15

    std::cout<<"Iterative Diode Voltage Calculator"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"__________________________________"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"Enter Voltage Source (V): ";
    std::cin>>V_PP;

    std::cout<<"Enter Resistance: (k"<<ohm<<"): ";
    std::cin>>R;
    R*=1000;

    std::cout<<"Enter Saturation Current (A) Enter 0 to leave it as "<<"2 "<<multi<< " 10" <<supNeg<<sup1<<sup5<<": ";
    double x;
    std::cin>>x;
    if(x){
        V_T = x;
    }

    std::cout<<"Enter Thermal Voltage (V) Enter 0 to leave it as 0.026 V : ";
    double y;
    std::cin>>y;
    if(y){
        V_T = y;
    }

    int old_V_D_lastDigit = int((old_V_D * 1000.0)) % 10; //third digit after decimal point 
    int new_V_D_lastDigit = 0;

    int iterationCount=0;

    while( new_V_D_lastDigit != old_V_D_lastDigit){       //3 digits after decimal point is close enough, no more iterations needed
        new_V_D = V_T * log( (V_PP - old_V_D) / (R * I_S) ); //The Formula takes old guess and gives a closer guess
        new_V_D_lastDigit = int((new_V_D * 1000.0)) % 10;
        old_V_D_lastDigit = int((old_V_D * 1000.0)) % 10;
        old_V_D = new_V_D;
        iterationCount++;
    }
    std::cout<<"Found Diode Voltage: "<<new_V_D<<" in "<<iterationCount<<" iterations"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Press any key to exit";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but I don't see anywhere in your code that you are using <Windows.h> (or anywhere that you are converting to or from UTF-8, not that Windows.h is needed for that).

Comment: You might try to compile with `-static` option, in order to avoid use of dll.

Comment: @john Yes, turns out it was not necessary, thank you. I edited the new compiled code.

Comment: @AliTeo It is nice that it works now. This issue is not new, and has been dealt with several times already on SO. Therefore I prefer not to post an answer that would be a duplicate. I have no time to look for a duplicate question now.

Comment: @Damien That is understandable. That is very kind you for giving an answer for a duplicate question instead of just telling me that is a duplicate question and look for a different answer.